# Not able to parse the character ! parameter in spark job server

Tags: json, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I am trying to submit a spark job in spark job server with input in json format. However in my case one of values contains '!' character, which is not allowing me to parse it.Here is my input and response.

Input

```
curl -d "{"test.input1"="abc", "test.input2"="def!"}" 'http://localhost:8090/jobs?appName=my_spark_job&classPath=com.example.spark.job.MySparkJob'
```

Response

```
"result": "Cannot parse config: String: 1: Reserved character '!' is not allowed outside quotes (if you intended '!' (Reserved character '!' is not allowed outside quotes) to be part of the value for 'test.input2', try enclosing the value in double quotes, or you may be able to rename the file .properties rather than .conf)"
```

The value of "test.input2" is already in double quotes. I tried adding single/double quotes but still didnt work. Any thoughts how can i parse it.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't there any escaping character? such as \? maybe try \! for the password. Just guessing here since its reserved character there must be escaping

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in a json file and do the following

```
curl --data-binary @/path/to/json/file 'http://localhost:8090/jobs?appName=my_spark_job&classPath=com.example.spark.job.MySparkJob'
```

Comment: I tried the option of passing json. It works . But my way of execution is different . The value for "test.input2" is actually a password. I have the curl command inside a python script and run the script passing the password from command line argument. If i put in json, i have to hardcode it in json file which is a security constraint for me

Comment: Why don't you use python-sjsclient?